# How to use powershell syntax within a json file?

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to run a powershell command within a json file which is for cloudformation template.  I am getting errors with anything after the pipe(|) symbol.

This is a new script that needs to work for our templates.

```
"commands": {
                        "UpdateAbsolutePath": {
                            "command": "powershell.exe -Command ((Get-Content -path D:\\Tomcat-8.0\\webapps\\lease_accelerator\\WEB-INF\\web.xml -Raw) -Replace \"LA-AWS-SU1-APP1\",\"LA-AWS-SU2-APP1\") | Set-Content -Path D:\\Tomcat-8.0\\webapps\\lease_accelerator\\WEB-INF\\web.xml"
                        }
```

I expect it to run fine, but I get the following error:

```
[DEBUG] No services specified
2019-06-05 13:49:01,572 [DEBUG] Running command UpdateAbsolutePath
2019-06-05 13:49:01,588 [DEBUG] No test for command UpdateAbsolutePath
2019-06-05 13:49:01,618 [ERROR] Command UpdateAbsolutePath (powershell.exe -Command ((Get-Content -path D:\Tomcat-8.0\webapps\lease_accelerator\WEB-INF\web.xml -Raw) -Replace "LA-AWS-SU1-APP1","LA-AWS-SU2-APP1") | Set-Content -Path D:\Tomcat-8.0\webapps\lease_accelerator\WEB-INF\web.xml) failed
2019-06-05 13:49:01,618 [DEBUG] Command UpdateAbsolutePath output: 'Set-Content' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

2019-06-05 13:49:01,618 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of config: Command UpdateAbsolutePath failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 513, in run_config
File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 125, in run_commands
File "cfnbootstrap\command_tool.pyc", line 113, in apply
ToolError: Command UpdateAbsolutePath failed
2019-06-05 13:49:01,618 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!----- 
-------------------
2019-06-05 13:49:01,618 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command UpdateAbsolutePath failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cfn-init", line 123, in <module>
File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 117, in build
File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 502, in build
File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 513, in run_config
File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 125, in run_commands
File "cfnbootstrap\command_tool.pyc", line 113, in apply
ToolError: Command UpdateAbsolutePath failed`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the command within double quotes or add a `^` before the pipe symbol.

Some valid and non-valid examples:

```
> powershell -Command Write-Output "OK" | Out-String
'Out-String' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

```
> powershell -Command Write-Output "OK" ^| Out-String
OK
```

```
> powershell -Command 'Write-Output "OK" | Out-String'
'Out-String' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

```
> powershell -Command "Write-Output `"OK`" | Out-String"
OK
```

```
> powershell -Command { Write-Output "OK" | Out-String }
'Out-String' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

```
> powershell -Command "& { Write-Output "OK" | Out-String}"
OK
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the `^` symbol before the pipeline symbol?